# EF includes nested entity only once

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Entity Framework doesn't include the nested entity with its data more than once.

Below is the response from Postman:

```
[{
    "ProjectID": 29,
    "ProjectName": "Angular",
    "ProjectDescription": "This is angular project for developing webpages.",
    "ProjectURL": "angular.com",
    "ApplicationEntity": [],
    "ApplicationID": 21
},
{
    "ProjectID": 30,
    "ProjectName": "Dot Net 6",
    "ProjectSlug": "MAUI",
    "ProjectDescription": "This is project for .net framwork MAUI.",
    "ProjectURL": "maui.com",
    "ApplicationEntity": [
        {
            "ApplicationID": 21,
            "ApplicationName": "Custom Application",
            "ApplicationVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "ApplicationDescription": "This is for a custom implementation."
        }
    ],
    "ApplicationID": 21
}]
```

As you can see the `"ApplicationID" : 21` is same in both the entries. But the `ApplicationEntity` doesn't include the values for it for `"ProjectID":29`.

CreateProject.cs

```
public ProjectEntity CreateProject(int id, ProjectEntity projectEntity)
    {

        projectEntity.ApplicationID = id;

        CustomerSupportDBContext dBContext = new CustomerSupportDBContext();
        ApplicationEntity applicationEntity = dBContext.ApplicationEntities.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ApplicationID == id);

        using (dBContext)
        {
            projectEntity.ApplicationEntity.Add(applicationEntity);
            dBContext.ProjectEntities.Add(projectEntity);
            dBContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return projectEntity;
    }
```

**EDIT:** ProjectController.cs

```
[Route("getAllProjects")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllProjects()
    {
        try
        {
            ProjectService projectService = new ProjectService();
            IQueryable<ProjectEntity> response = projectService.GetAllProjects();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

ProjectService.cs

```
public IQueryable<ProjectEntity> GetAllProjects()
    {
        CustomerSupportDBContext dBContext = new CustomerSupportDBContext();
        var projectEntities = dBContext.ProjectEntities.Include("ApplicationEntity");
        return projectEntities;
    }
```

ProjectEntity.cs

```
[Table("ProjectEntity")]
public class ProjectEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }        
    public string ProjectURL { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationEntity> ApplicationEntity { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }        

    public ProjectEntity()
    {
        ApplicationEntity = new List<ApplicationEntity>();
        IssueEntity = new List<IssueEntity>();
    }
}
```

ApplicationEntity.cs

```
[Table("ApplicationEntity")]
public class ApplicationEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationVersion { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationDescription { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext.cs

```
public class CustomerSupportDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ProjectEntity> ProjectEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationEntity> ApplicationEntities { get; set; }

    public CustomerSupportDBContext()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Only the last entity is having the `ApplicationEntity` with it's details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong in your implementation, and I suspect your mappings are doing something very strange to get things giving some semblance of working.

The obvious issue is that you are defining a 1-to-many relationship between Project and Application where ProjectEntity contains a collection of ApplicationEntity, however your FK relationship in the entities is backwards. ApplicationEntity should have a ProjectId rather than ProjectEntity having an ApplicationId.  I would start by looking closely at your resulting schema to determine exactly what and how these data rows are using to link to one another.

If Project has 0-1 Application, then ProjectEntity would have a null-able ApplicationId column, but would contain a single ApplicationEntity reference, not a `List<ApplicationEntity>`.  If a Project can have 0-many Applications, then ProjectEntity would have `List<ApplicationEntity>` but no ApplicationId, and instead, the ApplicationEntity would have a ProjectId mapped as the FK back to the Project.

Other issues:

Don't do this:

```
CustomerSupportDBContext dBContext = new CustomerSupportDBContext();
var projectEntities = dBContext.ProjectEntities.Include("ApplicationEntity");
return projectEntities;
```

Do this:

```
using (CustomerSupportDBContext dBContext = new CustomerSupportDBContext())
{
    var projectEntities = dBContext.ProjectEntities.Include("ApplicationEntity");
    return projectEntities;
}
```

Similarly, don't do this:

```
CustomerSupportDBContext dBContext = new CustomerSupportDBContext();
ApplicationEntity applicationEntity = dBContext.ApplicationEntities.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ApplicationID == id);

using (dBContext)
{
   // ...
```

use:

```
using (CustomerSupportDBContext dBContext = new CustomerSupportDBContext())
{
    ApplicationEntity applicationEntity = dBContext.ApplicationEntities.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ApplicationID == id);

    // ....
}
```

Always ensure that a DbContext is disposed if the project is not using dependency injection to manage its lifetime scope. This will break your `IQueryable` implementation because the DbContext will be disposed before the method returns. However, leaving a DbContext open like that is just asking for trouble with memory/db connection handle leaks.

`IQueryable<TEntity>` is a very flexible and powerful pattern for repositories but it can only work where the DbContext lifetime scope extends beyond the method returning the `IQueryable`. Either leveraging Dependency Injection so that the caller and Repository can share the same instance of the DbContext *AND* the DbContext will be guaranteed to be disposed at the end of the request, or using a Unit of Work wrapper for the DbContext that the repository/service can use to resolve the instance of the DbContext.

An example with a unit of work scope would be something more like:

```
using (var unitOfWork = ContextScopeFactory.Create())
{
    var project = ProjectService.GetProjectById(projectId)
        .Select(p => new ProjectViewModel 
        {
            // populate details about project and application(s) that View needs
        }).Single();
   return project;
}
```

Where ProjectService has a DbContext resolver to get a DbContext reference from a wrapping context scope. It's a bit more advanced example that can allow callers to project or choose what needs to be eager loaded leveraging the power of `IQueryable`. In your implementation you cannot rely on doing anything with `IQueryable` since the DbContext reference is left hanging, and the moment someone goes to fix a memory leak or open DB connection leak from that undisposed DbContext, that method will fail. (May as well return `IEnumerable<ProjectEntity>`.

Answer (score 1):

The ApplicatonEntity property on ProjectEntity is a List. This implies there can be more than one application per project. If a project has more than one application, what would the value of ApplicationId be on the ProjectEntity. I suspect ApplicationEntity is expected to be linked to a single Project hence only the last project picks up the application. I think the ApplicationEntity property should not be a list